# Options for a graphical EFI boot loader?

Tags: dual-boot, grub

So, after having resolved the issues with the [installer not being able to find the target disk](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/installer-doesnt-see-my-ssd), I was able to install Freya 0.3.2 and I am now able to start it by entering the BIOS menu where I can choose to Legacy boot. This takes me to the GRUB menu, so the boot process is currently a 2 step procedure.

The reason why I have to use the BIOS as a boot manager is probably because I installed GRUB to the wrong location. As it is now it works OK, but it's of course a bit cumbersome and not very pretty, so I'd like to set up a boot loader. "While at it", I thought I could just as well try to set up something that looks good. Preferably it should be something that matches the sleek and polished look of elementary itself, so a black & white text-only GRUB menu is something that I'd like to avoid.

I'd love to have something that looks like the ["El Castillo" BURG theme](http://bigrza.deviantart.com/art/El-Castillo-BURG-Theme-187228213), but as far as I know, BURG doesn't support (U)EFI (correct me if I'm wrong)

So, what options are there?

- GRUB with grub-customizer?
- rEFInd?
- Clover?

Answer (score 1):

rEFInd is the way to go. I use rEFInd on my UEFI laptop and I have not experienced any problems.

It is also highly customizable and has lots of themes to choose from and is actively developed by Rod Smith.

You can see some rEFInd themes at http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/themes.html

Also a guide for installing rEFInd http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html

Here's a picture of my laptop with rEFInd using the Next Theme with a custom wallpaper.

[image: refind]

Using my custom wallpaper I created in GIMP

[image: wallpaper]

Comment: Hehe, fun+beautiful wallpaper :) 

I finally went with Grub and the Vimix theme, it doesn't look as good as your boot screen but it's definitely better than the default text-only screen.

Now we're just waiting for someone to make a Grub theme based on your wallpaper :)

Comment: You can also use rEFInd if you have a UEFI or EFI machine

Comment: if you still want to use GRUB (maybe if you have BIOS) you can use http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/10/grub-splash-image/ with my wallaper

Comment: why wait? you can indicate the image as a background one using GRUB_BACKGROUND in /etc/default/grub